# Passing an ifstream variable between members of the same object, C++

Tags: c++, file, class, object, member

**Goal:** Using the class variable so that an ifstream declared in an object's member can be used by the following member of the same object, without having to use function header parameter passing.

**Problem:** The local ifstream of the created object test isn't being re-used in the second member of that object. I must be setting it up wrong, how do I fix this?

Classes and files feel like climbing a mountain to me right now, but I can't even find the first foothold - getting the blasted variable to work! I looked around the net for too long but all examples are convoluted, I just want to have something basic working to start tinkering with. I'm dead sure it's something stupidly easy that I'm missing, really frustrating >:[

**main.cpp**

```
#include "file.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    file test;
    test.file_pass();
    return 0;
}
```

**file.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class file
{
    public:

        file();
        void file_pass();

    //private:
        ifstream stream;
};

#endif
```

**file.cpp**

```
#include "file.h"

//**********************************
//This will read the file.
file::file()
{
    ifstream stream("Word Test.txt");
}

//**********************************
//This will output the file.
void file::file_pass()
{
   //ifstream stream("Word Test.txt"); //if line activated, program works fine of course.
    string line;
    while(getline(stream, line))
            cout << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you chould read/learn about C++ before asking on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are creating a new local variable with the same name as the class member:

```
file::file()
{
    ifstream stream("Word Test.txt");
}
```

Instead you can use this to initialize the class member in the constructor:

```
file::file() : stream("Word Test.txt")
{
}
```

Comment: Take all my upvotes and an answered question checkmark in 9 minutes when stack overflow lets me :)

I knew it was something simple I was missing haha